# Почему не происходит авторизация в Spring security?

Tags: java, spring-security, thymeleaf, аутентификация

Пользователь сохраняется в базу данных, но при попытке входа в аккаунт страница `/login` перезагружается

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.bulletin_board</groupId>
    <artifactId>bulletin_board</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bulletin board</name>
    <description>bulletin board</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration implements UserDetailsService {
    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/product/**", "/images/**", "/registration").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
            )
            .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll);

    return http.build();
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

### UserController:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration() {
        return "registration";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String createUser(User user) {
        userService.createNewUser(user);
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

/

### Страница login:

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <h1 class="text-center mb-4">Вход</h1>

                <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email"/>
                    <label class="form-label" for="email">Почта</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                    <input type="password" id="registerPassword" class="form-control" name="password"/>
                    <label class="form-label" for="registerPassword">Пароль</label>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:value="${_csrf.token}">

                <div class="col text-center">
                    <button type="submit" value="Вход" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-3">Вход</button>
                </div>

                <p class="text-center">or</p>

                <div class="col text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                        <img src="/images/google_icon-icons.com_62736.png" height="64" width="64"/>
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                        <img src="/images/vk_icon-icons.com_66102.png" height="64" width="64"/>
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                        <img src="/images/social_apple_mac_25.png" height="64" width="64"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Можно указать куда перенаправить пользователя при правильном вводе логина/пароля: `.loginPage("/login").successForwardUrl("/<mainPage>")`.

Answer (score 0):

Перенаправлять пользователя на страницу логина нельзя. Эта страница должна сама появляться при запросе защищённых страниц.

Неправильно:

```
return "redirect:/login";
```

Правильно:

```
return "redirect:/";
```

Comment: Учту. У меня в базе есть пользователи. Когда пытаюсь войти в аккаунт с через одного из пользователей (почту и пароль ввожу верно), то страница перезагружается и в ссылке появляется http://localhost:8080/login?error

Comment: Это перенаправление на страницу ошибок. Какое сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.